# Update ends in negative balance after massive update requests Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Currently, I've this method inside my models.py

```
 def charge(self, amount):
    self.balance = (self.balance - Decimal(amount))
    self.save()
```

When A new request comes in I check if that user has **current_balance >= price** So I can do objectRow.charge(price) the issue is when I get 1000 request to the same ID I end up in -000 negative balance and the users ends up owing me money and that's not the point.

This is my validation so far.

```
            accountObject = account.objects.get(auth_token=auth_token)

                        if accountObject.balance >= settings.MT_COST:

                            # Save
                            ProductObject = product(application=applicationObject,
                                                account=accountObject,
                                                cost=settings.MT_COST,
                                                direction=2,
                                                status_log=1,
                                                product=product_id,
                                                ip_address=ip_address)
                            ProductObject.save()

                            # Charge User
                            ProductObject.charge(settings.MT_COST)

                            data = {'status': "ok"}
                            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json', status=200)

                        # Not enough Balance
                        else:

                            data = {'status': "error"}
                            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json', status=406)
```

Comment: Hi, try to make method 'charge' thread safe.

Comment: @Abhijit will this make the other requests to server die or fail if one is updating? or make them wait and then be processed with the new balance update?

Comment: They will simply wait. You just try with lock at the begin and unlock at the end. Once other thread find it lock they will wait till it unlock.

Comment: @Abhijit have any example? Because that looks like transaction lock in postgres begin; commit; no??

Comment: Why don't you first try by making it thread safe? I don't see any side effect here.

Comment: Ended up using Celery for Queueing the Requests when saving..